# How do I set up checkboxes with jsTree?

Tags: javascript, jstree

I want to use jsTree with checkboxes but it does not work.

My code:

```js
$("#tree").jstree({
    "json_data" : {
        "data" : data
    },
    checkbox: true,
    checkboxName: 'checkbox1[]',
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "ui", "checkbox", "types" ]
});
```

The tree looks nice and works, but I don't have the checkboxes to select items.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I might be saying something stupid, because I don't know what jstree is, but maybe you need to do them in the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you. :)

```
$("#tree").jstree({
"plugins" : ["themes","json_data","ui","checkbox", "types"],
"json_data":{
    data : data
},
"checkbox": {
    two_state: true
}});
```